# QML/QtQuick: make Image occupy only available height in ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm developing a mobile app with QML/QtQuick and Qt 5.9.x (Qt 5.10+ is not an option because it doesn't support iOS 8 and 9).

In my vertical layout I'd like to make `Image` be automatically resized to available height, but I can't figure out how to achieve this: it's always shown in full height. My QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true

    // simulate iPhone 6
    width: 375
    height: 667

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        Text {
            text: qsTr("multiline text multiline text multiline text multiline text")
            textFormat: Text.PlainText
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            font { weight: Font.Normal; pointSize: 18 }

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.topMargin: 20
        }

        Text {
            text: qsTr("title1")
            textFormat: Text.PlainText
            font { weight: Font.DemiBold; pointSize: 50 }

            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.topMargin: 30
        }
        Text {
            text: qsTr("title2")
            textFormat: Text.PlainText
            font { weight: Font.DemiBold; pointSize: 25 }

            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }

        Image {
            source: "qrc:/Painting.jpg"
            verticalAlignment: Image.AlignTop
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop

//            Layout.preferredHeight: 200 // that's how I obtained the second screenshot, but using a constant is not an option of course
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.topMargin: 20
        }

        Text {
            text: qsTr("multiline text multiline text multiline text multiline text")
            textFormat: Text.PlainText
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            font { weight: Font.Normal; pointSize: 17 }

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.topMargin: 20
        }

        GridLayout {
            Layout.maximumWidth: 300
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.topMargin: 20
            Layout.bottomMargin: 30

            rows: 3
            columns: 3
            rowSpacing: 10
            columnSpacing: 10

            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"

                Layout.row: 0
                Layout.column: 0
                Layout.columnSpan: 3
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"

                Layout.row: 1
                Layout.column: 0
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"

                Layout.row: 1
                Layout.column: 1
                Layout.columnSpan: 2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"

                Layout.row: 2
                Layout.column: 0
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"

                Layout.row: 2
                Layout.column: 1
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"

                Layout.row: 2
                Layout.column: 2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First image is how it's shown now, second one is how I want it to be: (screenshots are from desktop, but on mobile the result is the same)

[image] [image]

I know how to achieve the desired behavior on iOS through AutoLayout (play with image's hugging priority and/or compression resistance), but I can't find anything similar in QML/QtQuick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Layout.fillHeight` will automatically resize the `Image` to the available height:

```
Image {
    // ...
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
    Layout.fillHeight: true
}
```